# Deploying Symfony App on Heroku - Error 500

Tags: php, symfony, heroku, webpack

I'm trying to deploy my Symfony App on Heroku, I'm a noob on Symfony, by following the docs.
I already setup my database, env variables, Procfiles but I still got an error 500.
From Heroku's log, it was built and deployed successfully however it seems there is an error of entrypoint from my Webpack.config.js but I don't have any issues on localhost.

```
2020-07-19T16:20:21.627915+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-19T16:20:21.331497+00:00] request.INFO: Matched route "homepage". {"route":"homepage","route_parameters":{"_route":"homepage","_controller":"App\\Controller\\HomeController::index"},"request_uri":"http://clone-air-bnb.herokuapp.com/","method":"GET"} []
2020-07-19T16:20:21.630003+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-19T16:20:21.624822+00:00] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Twig\Error\RuntimeError: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Could not find the entrypoints file from Webpack: the file "/app/public/build/entrypoints.json" does not exist.")." at /tmp/build_ba94d432_/templates/base.html.twig line 9 {"exception":"[object] (Twig\\Error\\RuntimeError(code: 0): An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template (\"Could not find the entrypoints file from Webpack: the file \"/app/public/build/entrypoints.json\" does not exist.\"). at /tmp/build_ba94d432_/templates/base.html.twig:9)\n[previous exception] [object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Could not find the entrypoints file from Webpack: the file \"/app/public/build/entrypoints.json\" does not exist. at /app/vendor/symfony/webpack-encore-bundle/src/Asset/EntrypointLookup.php:124)"} []
```

Here is my webpack config

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .addEntry('js/app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .addEntry('js/ad', './assets/js/ad.js')
    .addEntry('js/bootstrap-datepicker', './assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js')
    .addEntry('css/app', './assets/css/app.scss')
    .addEntry('css/bootstrap-datepicker', './assets/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css')
    .splitEntryChunks()
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })
    .enableSassLoader()
    .autoProvidejQuery()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Thanks